# Conditional Formatting with results from formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In cell C1 I have a simple formula showing a net change from two other cells.  =B1-A1

I would like to use the icon set in conditional formatting to show graphically the change, along with the result.

How do I define the conditional formatting to show only positive or negative results?

I would like the green arrow for positive changes and the red arrow for negative.  I can get part of this to work, but if I change the data in A1 or B1, the conditional formatting doesn't change the result.

Comment: How did you define the conditional format (the one that "doesn't work")

Answer (score 3):

I suggest two rules, one merely to take precedence over the icon set when C1 is zero (as adjusted for the accuracy required):

[image: SO19256108 example]

In the image the value in B1 is 99.99999

Comment: +1 Here's a [Bacon Bits post](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-stop-if-true-when-conditional-formatting/) that discusses this in depth.